# Binding a utility to an ip/port

Tags: linux, command-line, tcp

I just read in a book (from 2000) how a (unix/linux) server would listen on a port waiting for connections associated with a utility.

An example in the book is about the `finger` utility.

The netstat output on the server is like this:

```
proto recv-q send-q local address foreign address state    user
[..]
tcp     0         0          *.finger           *:*                      listen   root
[..]
```

So, `finger` is listening on the `finger`-port (which is 79).

A user then may connect (with telnet is this case) to the server at port 79, input a user name and see the output from the `finger` command:

```
... Connected to server
Escape character is '^]'.
guest                                                                                    <--- 
user input
Login: guest                             Name: guest                        <--- output from 
finger(?)
Directory: /dev/null                   Shell /dev/null
Never logged in.
No mail.
No plan.
```

Does anyone have any good explanation for how this is done?

My approach would be to connect to ssh on the server and then run `finger` from the command line interface.

Thanks!

Comment: You can start with reading books on client-server architecture. Google "client-server architecture textbook". Also, google "example http server in c" (or any other language you prefer). There are thousands of simple enough, but working servers. They could show how the server receives a request and sends a response.

Comment: Any good explanation for how _what_ is done?

Comment: Thanks. I thought this was more trivial, e.g. piping input/output from a utility to a network socket. It's more advanced I guess then.

Comment: it is pretty much that, though. You set up a socket (i.e., you tell it to what address and port to listen on), and then you have a loop accepting connections to that port. That's it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer myself; `inetd` was what I was looking for; *launch a program to process the connection*, e.g. `netstat`.

[Linux – Create custom inetd service](https://somoit.net/linux/linux-create-custom-inetd-service)

Thank you for helping me.